# Javascript sum function with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, function, sum, arguments

I have to do a sum function in java , with variable number of arguments , and the last argument is allways the id of the text field where the result will be displayed , I already tried to do a for with arguments.length and sum them , and after passing the result thru getElementById(lastargument).value=sum; but doesn't work.. Sorry if I can't be more explicit but I'm with the cell phone..

Comment: Javascript or Java ? Where is the code ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry I can't write my proper function because I'm with the phone , this is part of it.. I don't get any result : function sum(){ var sum=0; for(var i=0;i≤arguments.length-1;i++){var s=0; var sum_var = document.getElementById(arguments[i]).value; s+=sum_var;} document.getElementById(arguments[arguments.length]).value = s; }

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function sum(){
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0; i<argumenths.length - 1; i++){
    sum+=arguments[i];
  }

  document.getElementById(arguments[arguments.length - 1]).innerText=sum;
}
```

Comment: Can't work like that because as arguments I pass some input text id's , like this : Sum(\"id1\",\"id2\",\"id3\",\"idres\").. So what I want is to sum the first 3 or 4 or 5.. and then write the sum in the last id input text..